# Google Maps Directions in XML or JSON with other travel modes

Tags: ios, google-maps, directions

I'm trying to get the directions for travel modes other than driving but the api doesn't seem to respect the dirflg parameter.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=111%20Davisville%20Avenue,Toronto,ON&destination=469%20King%20Street%20West,%20Toronto,%20ON&sensor=false&dirflg=w

Can anyone tell me what the correct url is? Thank you in advance.

Comment: clicked on that URL, seems to be working for me

Comment: No, its showing driving directions, I want to get walking, cycling or even public_transit directions but I read public_transit is not available to the public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the parameter is mode, as in mode=walking:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=111%20Davisville%20Avenue,Toronto,ON&destination=469%20King%20Street%20West,%20Toronto,%20ON&sensor=false&mode=walking

Comment: Ah thank you so much! What are the other parameters? I tried cycling, cycle, public_transit with no success. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Ah its bicycling. Still don't know public transit though :(

Comment: Google isn't licensed to provide public transit data, as in the transit agencies don't grant that right to use their data. You can see the travel mode parameters here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#TravelModes

Comment: Are there any other API providers from other companies (that cover major cities of the world at least) for public transit? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but search for Google Transit Feed Spec or GTFS, some agencies are providing those as downloads.